# cannot getting arabic data from twitter using tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

i'm trying to get data from twitter using 
tweepy library on python i get this error i already tried some solutions like changing the Keys but still not working

```
import tweepy
import xlsxwriter
from TweetClassifier import TweetClassifier
from DataCleaner import DataCleaner
import pandas as pd
import os
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
class TwitterAPI:

    tweets = None
    query = None
    number_of_tweets = 100
    date = None
    consumer_key = "vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6"
    consumer_secret = "Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvv"
    access_token = "295xxx24-eYxxxxxxerE9"
    access_secret = "V2xxxxxxxxWadL"
    data_clean = DataCleaner()
    tweets_classifier = TweetClassifier()

    def __init__(self):

        return

    def Auth(self):

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(self.consumer_key, self.consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(self. access_token, self.access_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        return api

        def retrieve_tweets(self, query, api):
            tweets = []
            for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(100):
                tweets.append(tweet.text)
            return tweets
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsgBL.png)

Comment: Can you paste that error into the question?

Comment: HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. So this is a login problem.

Comment: When you post the stack trace, include the whole thing so we see which line in your program failed.